# Single php file for both html and server side events page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, eventsource

I use this code to have the same file for both html page and dynamic ajax response (using jQuery):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    echo "AJAX reponse";
    exit;
}

?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Leash</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
       $.get('', function(data) { alert(data); });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

is it possible to do the same using Server Side Evens and EventSource?

Comment: Maybe you wanna try out WebSocket and some EventDriven backend like eg NodeJS? think it would be a better fit

Comment: @Endless I'm trying to run this on shared hosting where I don't have access to Node only php and CGI scripts and all ports are closed by firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the headers in developer tools there is `Accept: text/event-stream` so you can check for presence of the header using:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && preg_match("%text/event-stream%", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])) {

// server side events code
}?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
</html><?php } ?>
```